# How does return terminate all instances of a recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

How does return terminates all the instances in a recursion?  In the following it seems to me that the only time the return statement is called is in the base case and yet it seems to close all of the other instances where n is > 1.

```
def reco(n):
   print('create instance nbr ', n)
   if n == 1:
      print('base case reached, instances will be popped LIFO') 
      return
   else:
       n -= 1
       reco(n)
   print('pop instance nbr ', n)


n = 5
reco(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the `return` statement only executes once, but the `reco()` call is the second-to-last statement in all the other instances. The execution just falls out the end of the other instances.

It might help if you imagined that every function body has an implicit `return None` statement at the end.